# AJAX call response, event is not defined only in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

I have a form for in-app chat that creates the message itself in the db and then via AJAX the message gets displayed. For other reasons I have to make sure that after submission the js response fires only once, so I put there `if(event.handled !== true)`. Without this conditional, both firefox and chrome work fine, but if I put this in the code then chrome still works but firefox sends this error: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`. What's going on here? What should I do to have it working with ff as well?

js for submitting

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.chatboxtextarea', function (event) {
  var id = $(this).data('cid');
  checkInputKey(event, $(this), id);
});

function checkInputKey(event, chatboxtextarea, conversation_id) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey == 0) {
    event.preventDefault();
    message = chatboxtextarea.val();
    if (message != '') {
      $('#conversation_form_' + conversation_id).submit();
    }
  }
};
```

js.erb (rails backend response if submit is successful, e.g. message gets saved)

```
if(event.handled !== true) {

    $message = $('<%= j render @message %>');
    chatbox.append($message);

    $(".chatboxtextarea").val("");
    $(".chatboxtextarea").focus();

    event.handled = true;
}
```

Comment: In Chrome and IE the `event` argument is global, while in Firefox it's not, so somewhere you're missing the argument and relying on the global `event` instead.

Comment: "In rails he ajax JS is evaluated in global scope.". I'm not good at JS and jQuery. Could you tell me how to change the code to make it working in ff as well? Besides that couly you tell me if this global event argument can cause some problems later on?